# Unexpected 'X' value of reset in verilog gate level simulation

Tags: verilog, reset

I am running gate level simulation for the verilog netlist after synthesis to do a functional verification. However the reset value is 'X' when it should be '0' at the beginning of simulation. From the figure we can see the input dsc_reset_b_r is 0, however after it is connected to the inverters the value changed to 'X', which is not expected. And for the same design and testbench, the rtl simulation works totally fine

[Schematic from Simvision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjLPn.png)

What can cause the 'X' of reset?

Comment: you need to provide verilog code for your reset signal and inverters. Otherwise it is impossible to guess what is going on in your model.

Comment: Could anything else be driving `dsc_reset_b`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other sources that drive dsc_reset_b. I just accidentally fixed this problem by changing the synthesis script, not sure which command caused the problem though.